Bloomberg installed but API folder is missing
This issue is happening on my work PC. After uninstalling and reinstalling Bloomberg and MS Office several times. The issue persists. My IT spend 5 hours on this, with Bloomberg support's help. Truly a freaking mystry why this is happening..
**The issue is ** After installing Bloomberg + Bloomberg Office Plugin. The excel bloomberg plugin is still missing. There is no sign of bloomberg plugin in my excel.
Can't run diagnostic tools because the diagnostic tool doesn't even exist.
in the C:\blp folder, there should be a folder called API, which has a bunch of stuff in it. The entire API folder is missing. It's like Bloomberg installs on my machine but doesn't install the entire API folder.
Anyone know what this is about? It's so weird that is almost fascinating. THank you,
My IT tried uninstall, reinstall a bunch of times. Bloomberg support desk was with my IT and tried playing around with different files. Still none worked.

That's not really a programming question. Could be a permission issue or maybe some process (like EXCEL.exe - check the task manager) is running and preventing the installation of the plugin.
